# JSTL: How to get previous and next iteration elements of Map?

Tags: java, javascript, dictionary, jstl, el

I have a TreeMap in my servlet and populate it as follows:

```
            Map<Integer, ClockTrans> ctsDictionary = new TreeMap<Integer, ClockTrans>();
            ClockTrans cts = null;

            for (int i = 0; i < ctsArr.length; i++) {
                cts = ctsArr[i];
                ctsDictionary.put(i, cts);
            }
```

Then in my JSP, I need to display the value of the previous, current and next/upcoming iteration values. For simplicity, in the code below, I removed the checks for first and last row to avoid index out of bounds errors.  But my main concern is the part where I use "status.index+1" to read ahead the next iteration value is not working.  What's the proper syntax to read the previous and next values?

```
            <c:forEach items="${ctsDictionary}" var="cts" varStatus="status">

                <tr>
                    <td align="center">
                        PREV: <c:out value='${cts[status.index-1].value.clock_no}'/>
                        CURR: <c:out value='${cts.value.clock_no}'/> 
                        NEXT: <c:out value='${cts[status.index+1].value.clock_no}'/>
                    </td>
                </tr>   

            </c:forEach>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't used this before, but my guess is you need to use `${ctsDictionary[status.index-1]` instead of `${cts[status.index-1]` because cts is only the current item.